# AWS Step Function - Dynamic parallelism MaxConcurrency Field

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-step-functions

We are using Step functions dynamic parallelism with Map state to achieve concurrency.
Is it possible to pass the values to "MaxConcurrency" field from its upstream task(lambda or read from file ) in map state stepfunctions .

Current code:

```
"Type": "Map",
"InputPath": "$.detail",
"ItemsPath": "$.shipped",
"MaxConcurrency": 3,
"ResultPath": "$.detail.shipped",
```

Expectation(pass input to MaxConcurrency from lambda task or read file task ):

```
 "Type": "Map",
 "InputPath": "$.detail",
 "ItemsPath": "$.shipped",
 "MaxConcurrency": "$.input",
 "ResultPath": "$.detail.shipped"
```

Getting error as it supports only integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `maxConcurrency` at state machine definition-time, but not at execution-time.  As you experienced, Map's `maxConcurrency` expects a `number`, but the state machine language uses `strings` to pass variables dynamically.

(**Note**: Step Functions are concurrent by default.  [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html): `maxConcurrency`'s *"default value is 0, which places no quota on parallelism and iterations are invoked as concurrently as possible"*.)

##### Option 1: Choice + Map (Difficulty: Low)

A workaround that *limits* concurrency dynamically at execution-time is a [Choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) that branches to discrete map states based on an input variable.  Each branch's Map has a different `maxConcurrency`, but is otherwise identical.  Add whichever discrete `maxConcurrency` choices you need.  Choice also accepts a default case to catch unmatched choice input.

```json
// execution input
{
  "concurrency": 5,
  "jobs": [ { "jobId": 1 }, { "jobId": 2 }, { "jobId": 3 }, { "jobId": 4}]
}
```

```json
// state machine definition (partial)
"States": {
  "Max-Concurrency-Choice": {
    "Type": "Choice",
    "Choices": [
      {
        "Variable": "$.concurrency",
        "NumericEquals": 5,
        "Next": "MapState-MaxConcurrency-5"  // maxConcurrency in this branch is set at 5
      },
      {
        "Variable": "$.concurrency",
        "NumericEquals": 10,
        "Next": "MapState-MaxConcurrency-10" // maxConcurrency in this branch is set at 10
      }
    ],
    "Default": "MapState-MaxConcurrency-1" // maxConcurrency in the default branch is set at 1
  },
```

[image: choice state machine screenshot]

##### Option 2: Nested Sfn + API Call (Difficulty: High)

Nest your Sfn in a new Sfn.  The new, parent Sfn takes a `maxConcurrency` in the input.  It has two tasks:

1. In a Lambda Task, call the [UpdateStateMachine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sfn/interfaces/updatestatemachinecommandinput.html) API with new stringified JSON state machine definition for your current, child Sfn.
2. Invoke your current State Machine.  The Sfn will have the new `maxConurrency`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply. Still am finding solutions to achieve concurrency in a single map state by passing the input from a file and change it based on the number of loads. Is it a limitation in StepFunctions ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your goal. If you want as much concurrency as possible, Step Functions does this out of the box.  Use `maxConcurrency` only if you want to _limit_ concurrency.  My answer allows you to limit it dynamically.  I have edited the answer a bit. If it is still not helpful, please edit your question to add specifics, perhaps with an example.

Comment: Lets say currently am setting Maxconcurrency as 10... After 3 months, i want to update Maxconcurrency as 20. My goal is to set this value from a variable (value of the variable stored in file) and pass the variable to MaxConcurrency Field of my state machine definition.  Trying options to avoid the change in StepFunctions definitions instead making it in the file directly whenever i want to increase or decrease the concurrency.

Comment: `maxConcurrency` is part of the definition.  The first sentence of my answer says: _You can set maxConcurrency at state machine definition-time, but not at execution-time._.  You have to change the definition to change `maxConcurrency`.
I have added a theoretical second workaround that automates what your comment asks for. This new option is quite complex, though.

Comment: Thanks..Let me try and post here..

Comment: @fedonev, unless I am missing something, the second option can run into a race condition if you have multiple concurrent executions for which different max concurrencies are desired.